# Why I cannot see line numbers in gdb backtrace?

Tags: c, gdb, icc

I cannot see line numbers in gdb. I have compiled everything with -g flags with mpiicc.

gdb is not showing line numbers even for breakpoints for me.

May be the problem is in "Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64 numactl-2.0.9-2.el6.x86_64" but I am not a superuser so I cannot install these.

```
 gdb  --args ./central -g 5 51
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-83.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/dslavchev/NuclearTesting/MPI/project-a-test-mpi/central...done.
(gdb) break direct.c:55
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40855d: file direct.c, line 55.
(gdb) l direct.c:55
50  
51  void direct(int* N, double **PA, Coord **points)
52  {
53      int     i ,j ,k ,l, ir, irr,
54              md = suma(N , NUM_AIRFOILS) - NUM_AIRFOILS,
55              m;
56      double  *D, // **D,
57              *A, *sv;
58  
59      int matrix_size_D = md*md;
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/dslavchev/NuclearTesting/MPI/project-a-test-mpi/central -g 5 51
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040855d in direct ()
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64 numactl-2.0.9-2.el6.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000040855d in direct ()
#1  0x0000000000405ee9 in main ()
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function direct,
which has no line number information.
PMPI_Comm_size (comm=1140850688, size=0x7fffffffc240) at ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c:57
57  ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c: No such file or directory.
    in ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c
(gdb) s
65  in ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c
(gdb) s
57  in ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c
(gdb) 
58  in ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c
(gdb) 
59  in ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c
(gdb) 
65  in ../../src/mpi/comm/comm_size.c
(gdb)
```

Here is the build commands as well:

```
mpiicc -g -c -o central.o central.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -c -o contours.o contours.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -c -o mymath.o mymath.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -c -o vort.o vort.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -qopenmp   -I/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2017.2.050/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mkl/include -c -o  direct.o direct.c 
mpiicc -g -c -o a_liftarg.o a_liftarg.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -c -o psavel.o psavel.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -c -o euler.o euler.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -c -o streamline.o streamline.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -c -o speedmap.o speedmap.c -qopenmp 
mpiicc -g -o central central.o contours.o mymath.o vort.o direct.o a_liftarg.o psavel.o euler.o streamline.o speedmap.o /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2017.2.050/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a -Wl,--start-group /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2017.2.050/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2017.2.050/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2017.2.050/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2017.2.050/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a -Wl,--end-group -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl -qopenmp
```

Comment: `I have compiled everything with -g flags` - no you didn't. You didn't compile glibc, you used glibc provided by your system. And it is provided without debugging info.

Comment: That does not matter. Line numbers appear to be absent in user code in `direct.c` file.

Comment: @ Kamil Cuk I am not interested in debuging glibc. My real issue is a segmentation fault, that I couldn't track because the debugger couldn't show me meaningful tracking information. printf debugging won the day for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May be the problem is

No: the problem is not that (neither `main`, not `direct` are defined in `libc`).

This appears to be a bug in GDB: before you execute `run`, it clearly knows that the address `0x40855d` corresponds to `direct.c, line 55`.

But after `run`, it somehow forgets that it knew this.

Your version of GDB is also 9 years old. As the first step, I suggest building a current version ([8.3 as of today](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Comment: To be honest I am not sure if this is the right answer but I suspect that the old gdb was the culprit. I eventually solved the problem with printf debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the flag

`-debug expr-source-pos`

It should add the line informations

https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-debug-linux-and-macos